# Can I bind to this array

Tags: javascript, json, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

A second set of eyes will help. I have a JSON string I'm reading from a RESTFUL endpoint. I want to declare the datasource separately "var dataSourceGLDes" and bind different DropDownLists to the data source. I'm getting an undefined result for the following:

```
GLDes: [{"gldes":"Comm "},{"gldes":"Indus "},{"gldes":"Auth "},{"gldes":"Res "},{"gldesc":"Whole "}]

$("#cboSearchString1DDL").kendoDropDownList({
                               autoBind: false,
                               dataTextField: "gldes",
                               dataValueField: "gldes",
                               dataSource: dataSourceGLDes,                                                                     
                           }).data("kendoDropDownList");

var dataSourceGLDes = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                   serverFiltering: true,
                   transport: {                          
                       read: {
                           url: _urlSOEResources,
                           dataType: "json"
                       }
                   },
                   schema: {
                       data: "GLDes"
                   }
               });
               dataSourceGLDes.read();
```

Answer (score 0):

What you shared seems to be working fine, just the order of declaring the dataSource and the kendo Grid looks wrong.

[Here](http://jsbin.com/UMESERu/2/edit) is live example that you can try (just switched the read operation to be function to simulate server call, rest is the same)

```
  <input type="text" id="cboSearchString1DDL">
  <script>

    var t  = {GLDes: [{"gldes":"Comm "},{"gldes":"Indus "},{"gldes":"Auth "},{"gldes":"Res "},{"gldesc":"Whole "}]}



var dataSourceGLDes = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                   serverFiltering: true,
                   transport: {                          
                     read: function(options){
                       options.success(t);
                     }
                   },
                   schema: {
                       data: "GLDes"
                   }
               });
               dataSourceGLDes.read();

  $("#cboSearchString1DDL").kendoDropDownList({
                               autoBind: false,
                               dataTextField: "gldes",
                               dataValueField: "gldes",
                               dataSource: dataSourceGLDes,                                                                     
                           }).data("kendoDropDownList");
```

Comment: I was a slacker when posting the order and the data. The order I had correct, however, the data was an html view of my json string which is properly escaped. So I still have the issue. `"GLDes": "[{\"gldes\":\"Comm\"},{\"gldes\":\"Indus\"},...]",